# SQLTimeout when executing stored procedure in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm getting an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired

with a stored procedure when the result set is above a certain record count. Unfortunately this error is only occurring in a production environment which I have very limited access to.

This is a legacy application and I didn't build this stored procedure, so I have to be careful about changes altering it's expected (but undocumented) behavior. I have a .NET background, but limited SQL Server experience.

The highest number of records that could be returned is 5000 (this is how many records are currently in the db). I don't know the exact threshold where it starts to fail, but it's somewhere between 2500 and the maximum 5000 records.

The stored procedure in question consists only of two `SELECT` statements unioned together. Using SQL Server Profiler on my dev machine didn't reveal anything useful. Is there anything obviously wrong with this stored procedure that would cause it to exceed the 30 second timeout?

```
SELECT     
    tblRed.PhaseID, tblRed.EventID, tblRed.RMUserID, tblRed.BackupRMUserID, 
    tblRed.AuthorUserID, tblRed.StageID, tblRed.Status, 
    tblRed.PublicationDateActual, tblGreen.SystemName, tblGreen.StakeholderDisplayName, 
    tblGreen.StakeholderQueue, tblRed.EventTypeID, 
    tblRed.StageReceivedDate, tblRed.StageDueDate, tblRed.SubmitDate, tblBlue.Name, 
    tblBlue.Email, tblBlue.PhoneNumber, tblBrown.EventName, 
    MIN(tblCharm.CommunicationMaterialTypeName) AS CommunicationMaterialTypeName, 
    MIN(tblUp.AttachmentID) AS AttachmentID, 
    tblOld.SmartFormID, tblOld.isGenerated, 
    MIN(tblStrange.SupportDocumentTypeID)  AS SupportDocumentTypeName
FROM
    tblDude 
INNER JOIN
    tblDown ON tblDude.TeamID = tblDown.TeamID 
INNER JOIN
    tblGrey ON tblGrey.DepartmentID = tblDown.DepartmentID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblOrange ON tblOrange.DepartmentID = tblGrey.DepartmentID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblPurple ON tblPurple.TeamID = tblDown.TeamID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblPaper ON tblGrey.DivisionID = tblPaper.DivisionID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblNavy ON tblPaper.DivisionID = tblNavy.DivisionID 
INNER JOIN
    tblRed ON tblRed.PhaseID = tblDude.PhaseID 
INNER JOIN
    tblGreen ON tblRed.StageID = tblGreen.StageID 
INNER JOIN
    tblBlue ON tblBlue.UserID = tblRed.AuthorUserID 
INNER JOIN
    tblBrown ON tblBrown.EventID = tblRed.EventID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblUp ON tblUp.PhaseID = tblRed.PhaseID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblCharm ON tblUp.CommunicationMaterialTypeID = tblCharm.CommunicationMaterialID 
              AND tblUp.isLatest = 'True' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblOld ON tblOld.PhaseID = tblRed.PhaseID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblStrange ON tblStrange.PhaseID = tblRed.PhaseID
WHERE     
    ((tblRed.AuthorUserID <> @UserID) 
     AND (tblRed.Status = 'Active') 
     AND (tblGreen.StakeholderQueue = 'History') 
     AND (tblDude.SMEUserID = @UserID)) 
    OR
    ((tblRed.AuthorUserID <> @UserID) 
     AND (tblRed.Status = 'Active') 
     AND (tblGreen.StakeholderQueue = 'History') 
     AND (tblGrey.DeptSignatoryUserID = @UserID)) 
    OR
    ((tblRed.AuthorUserID <> @UserID) 
     AND (tblRed.Status = 'Active') 
     AND (tblGreen.StakeholderQueue = 'History') 
     AND (tblPurple.DelegateUserID = @UserID)) 
    OR
    ((tblRed.AuthorUserID <> @UserID) 
     AND (tblRed.Status = 'Active') 
     AND (tblGreen.StakeholderQueue = 'History') 
     AND (tblOrange.DelegateUserID = @UserID)) 
    OR
    ((tblRed.AuthorUserID <> @UserID) 
     AND (tblRed.Status = 'Active') 
     AND (tblGreen.StakeholderQueue = 'History') 
     AND (tblNavy.UserID = @UserID)) 
    OR
    ((tblRed.AuthorUserID <> @UserID) 
     AND (tblRed.Status = 'Active') 
     AND (tblGreen.StakeholderQueue = 'History') 
     AND (tblPaper.DivisionSignatoryUserID = @UserID))
GROUP BY 
    tblRed.PhaseID, tblRed.EventID, tblRed.RMUserID, tblRed.BackupRMUserID, 
    tblRed.AuthorUserID, tblRed.StageID, tblRed.Status, tblRed.PublicationDateActual, 
    tblGreen.SystemName, tblGreen.StakeholderDisplayName, tblGreen.StakeholderQueue, 
    tblRed.EventTypeID, tblRed.StageReceivedDate, tblRed.StageDueDate, tblRed.SubmitDate, 
    tblBlue.Name, tblBlue.Email, tblBlue.PhoneNumber, tblBrown.EventName, 
    tblOld.SmartFormID, tblOld.isGenerated

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT 
   tblRed.PhaseID, tblRed.EventID, tblRed.RMUserID, tblRed.BackupRMUserID, 
   tblRed.AuthorUserID, tblRed.StageID, tblRed.Status, 
   tblRed.PublicationDateActual, tblGreen.SystemName, tblGreen.StakeholderDisplayName, 
   tblGreen.StakeholderQueue, tblRed.EventTypeID, 
   tblRed.StageReceivedDate, tblRed.StageDueDate, tblRed.SubmitDate, tblBlue.Name, 
   tblBlue.Email, tblBlue.PhoneNumber, tblBrown.EventName,  
   MIN(tblCharm.CommunicationMaterialTypeName) AS CommunicationMaterialTypeName, 
   MIN(tblUp.AttachmentID) AS AttachmentID, 
   tblOld.SmartFormID, tblOld.isGenerated, 
   MIN(tblStrange.SupportDocumentTypeID) AS SupportDocumentTypeName
FROM         
   tblRed 
INNER JOIN
   tblGreen ON tblRed.StageID = tblGreen.StageID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   tblBlue ON tblRed.RMUserID = tblBlue.UserID 
INNER JOIN
   tblBrown ON tblRed.EventID = tblBrown.EventID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   tblUp ON tblUp.PhaseID = tblRed.PhaseID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   tblCharm ON tblUp.CommunicationMaterialTypeID = tblCharm.CommunicationMaterialID 
            AND tblUp.isLatest = 'True' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   tblOld ON tblOld.PhaseID = tblRed.PhaseID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   tblStrange ON tblStrange.PhaseID = tblRed.PhaseID
WHERE 
   tblRed.Status = 'Active' 
   AND tblGreen.AuthorQueue = 'History' 
   AND tblRed.AuthorUserID = @UserID
GROUP BY 
   tblRed.PhaseID, tblRed.EventID, tblRed.RMUserID, tblRed.BackupRMUserID, 
   tblRed.AuthorUserID, tblRed.StageID, tblRed.Status, 
   tblRed.PublicationDateActual, tblGreen.SystemName, tblGreen.StakeholderDisplayName, 
   tblGreen.StakeholderQueue, tblRed.EventTypeID, tblRed.StageReceivedDate, 
   tblRed.StageDueDate, tblRed.SubmitDate, tblBlue.Name, tblBlue.Email, 
   tblBlue.PhoneNumber, tblBrown.EventName, tblOld.SmartFormID, tblOld.isGenerated
```

Comment: That's a `WHERE` clause that can certainly be compacted, though I would hope the query optimizer is clever enough. And why can't a heap of JOINs produce more result rows than the number of rows in the database?

Comment: Have you run the select query through the SQL Performance Analyser?  It might show you if there's a missing index that could help you.